# Basic Firebase and React issue resulting in "function is undefined"

Tags: reactjs, firebase, undefined, browserify

Using : React.js,Firebase and Browserify

I'm doing a simple tutorial and I'm 95% the error is just some noob mistake. I've been searching and tweaking for awhile now but I'm stuck

Error: This warning **FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: undefined is not a function**lead to this error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

Insight: According to the compiler my helper method "addPosts" is undefined when it is called by the eventlistener for the "child_added method.

Code:

```
var ChatServerActionCreators = require('../actions/ChatServerActionCreators');
var firebaseUrl = "https://changedthispurposely.firebaseio.com";

//Up here I will place my firebase event handler
var postBoxRef = new Firebase(firebaseUrl + "/post");
var posts = {};

function addPosts(author,text){
  posts.push({"author":author,"text":text});
}


postBoxRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var newPost = snapshot.val();
  addPosts(newPost.author, newPost.text);
});



module.exports = {
  getAllPosts: function() {
    var rawPosts = posts;
    console.log(rawPosts);
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh man. This was a simple fix. You can't "push" to an object. I switched out the  "posts" object for an array and now it's working!

posts = {};   <----retarded
posts = [];   <----The Fix